# Lagom with Gradle - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1$class

Tags: scala, gradle, playframework, lagom

I am trying to run a Lagom service using Gradle - this might not seem to be a good idea, but I decided to give it a try for learning purposes.

You can browse the repository here:
https://github.com/ashofthephoenix/lagom-gradle-helloworld

When I `cd` into hello-impl and execute `gradle -t runPlayBinary` in the console - the service works.

When I run the same command from the project level directory, it gives me this stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1$class
    at play.docs.Memoise.<init>(DocumentationHandler.scala:118)
    at play.docs.DocumentationHandler.<init>(DocumentationHandler.scala:26)
    at play.docs.DocumentationHandler.<init>(DocumentationHandler.scala:22)
    at play.docs.BuildDocHandlerFactory.fromJar(BuildDocHandlerFactory.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.play.internal.run.DefaultVersionedPlayRunAdapter.getBuildDocHandler(DefaultVersionedPlayRunAdapter.java:140)
    at org.gradle.play.internal.run.PlayWorkerServer.startServer(PlayWorkerServer.java:91)
    at org.gradle.play.internal.run.PlayWorkerServer.start(PlayWorkerServer.java:76)
    at org.gradle.play.internal.run.PlayWorkerServer.execute(PlayWorkerServer.java:60)
    at org.gradle.play.internal.run.PlayWorkerServer.execute(PlayWorkerServer.java:36)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:83)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:35)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:119)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:64)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:62)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function1$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 19 more
```

Could somebody tell me what is the problem here?

Thank you.

Comment: Check your scala version

Comment: It is set to 2.12. Should it be downgraded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lagom provides sbt and Maven plugins to allow them to launch multiple services, inject configuration into each, and allow them to discover each other using a service locator.

To do the same in Gradle would require writing a similar Gradle plugin. No such thing exists currently. Gradle's Play support has only been designed to work with traditional Play projects that contain a single application.

There is an open feature request to add official Gradle support to Lagom (https://github.com/lagom/lagom/issues/146).

Answer (score 1):

Although your build.gradle files have some redundancies, but it does build for me with `gradle clean :hello-impl:runPlayBinary` (yeah, the root level `gradle runPlayBinary` did report like yours, but I think your play setup is in your impl module.)

Let me know if `gradle clean :hello-impl:runPlayBinary` works for you.

```
$ gradle clean :hello-impl:runPlayBinary

> Task :hello-impl:compilePlayBinaryScala
Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

16:07:45.432 [info] play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer [] - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

> Task :hello-impl:runPlayBinary
Running Play App (:hello-impl:runPlayBinary) at http://localhost:9000/


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
8 actionable tasks: 8 executed

Reloadable deployment detected. Entering continuous build.

> Task :hello-impl:compilePlayBinaryScala
Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s
8 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 2 up-to-date

Waiting for changes to input files of tasks... (ctrl-d to exit)
16:07:55.872 [info] akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger [] - Slf4jLogger started
16:07:56.323 [info] akka.remote.Remoting [sourceThread=play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4, akkaSource=akka.remote.Remoting, sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=21:07:56.322UTC] - Starting remoting
16:08:01.482 [info] akka.remote.Remoting [sourceThread=play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4, akkaTimestamp=21:08:01.482UTC, akkaSource=akka.remote.Remoting, sourceActorSystem=application] - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://application@10.0.0.173:2552]
16:08:01.484 [info] akka.remote.Remoting [sourceThread=play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4, akkaTimestamp=21:08:01.483UTC, akkaSource=akka.remote.Remoting, sourceActorSystem=application] - Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://application@10.0.0.173:2552]
16:08:01.498 [info] akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://application) [sourceThread=play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4, akkaTimestamp=21:08:01.498UTC, akkaSource=akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application] - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://application@10.0.0.173:2552] - Starting up...
16:08:01.578 [info] akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://application) [sourceThread=play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4, akkaTimestamp=21:08:01.578UTC, akkaSource=akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application] - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://application@10.0.0.173:2552] - Registered cluster JMX MBean [akka:type=Cluster]
16:08:01.579 [info] akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://application) [sourceThread=play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4, akkaTimestamp=21:08:01.578UTC, akkaSource=akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application] - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://application@10.0.0.173:2552] - Started up successfully
16:08:01.602 [info] akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://application) [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15, akkaSource=akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=21:08:01.601UTC] - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://application@10.0.0.173:2552] - No seed-nodes configured, manual cluster join required
16:08:02.307 [info] play.api.http.EnabledFilters [] - Enabled Filters (see <https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters>):


16:08:02.348 [info] play.api.Play [] - Application started (Dev)
<-------------> 0% WAITING
```

[UPDATE]

Here is components task difference between `root` module, and `hello-impl` module. As you can see that the module settings is different between `root` module and your `hello-impl` module.

The artifact generated by `hello-impl` module would be the final deliverable, so from what I can see, the task should run by `:hello-impl:runPlayBinary`.

[image: Components task difference between root module and hello-impl module]

Comment: Yes, it works. but if I wanted to launch the whole project(which will contain at least 3-4 modules) how would I do that? Thank you for this solution by the way :)

Comment: @PawełKiersznowski, I need you to further show me the project setup. But i think it would be pretty much this to run the final task.  Even it is multi-module build, you can use compile (":module1"); to link them all together, and still use `:hello-impl:runPlayBinary` to do the final run for the artifact. check with this, https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Comment: If you meant adding `compile project (':welcome-impl')` (and its api module) to hello-impl build.gradle, then it's not working.

Comment: No, I mean that you should have one `runPlayBinary `?

Comment: Well.. that one `runPlayBinary` should be the root project, `hello-impl` shouldn't be used as the point of starting the application. Just one of the few modules that should be launched when you launch `runPlayBinary` on the root level

Comment: So each module has its own packaging, like `hello-api` generate jar, while `hello-impl` may generate war, the root folder is just a wrapper to include the submodules, so I still think you should run with `:hello-impl:runPlayBinary`

Comment: Alright. what if I wanted to add other modules? `stream-api` and `stream-impl` and a lot other ones?

Comment: Yeah, if that is the case, I think you will need to run `xx-impl:runPlayBinary` separately?

Comment: Not possible - it acts as if it were a different application since its trying to run under the same host as the other microservices. I want everything running as it should be, that is - just as if you launched it with Maven.